# r - How to change the order of a factor within another factor - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have an issue with ggplot2. I need to plot a bar chart of an independent variable divided in two factors (x and fill). However within the two levels of the x factor, my independent variable has to be ordered differently.

I tried using the factor function, but it orders the factor itself and not the levels differently.

```
# here is the str of the df

 $ Indep_var: int  90 70 30 50
 $ Factor_1 : Factor w/ 2 levels "One","Two": 2 2 1 1
 $ Factor_2 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Area1","Area2": 1 2 1 2
 $ SE       : num  3 4 3.5 5

# here is the code of the plot

ggplot(df, aes(x=Factor_1, y=Indep_var, fill=Factor_2)) +
geom_col(colour="black",width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Indep_var-SE, ymax=Indep_var+SE), width=0.2, position=position_dodge(0.5))

p2 + scale_fill_grey(start=0.8, end=0.4) + theme_classic() + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))
```

I need that my Indep_var is sorted as Area1-Area2 (that are levels of Factor_2) in the first level of Factor_1 (i.e. "One") and Area2-Area1 in the second level of Factor_1 (i.e. "Two").

Can someone specify the code that I need to add?

I hope it's clear enough. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand (correct me if I am wrong), within each group of `Factor_1`, you want to plot the bars placing the one with smaller value of `Indep_var` in the left and the one with larger value of `Indep_var` in the right. And then map the fill color to `Factor_2`.

I am not sure this is the best way to do it, but i created a new column with his ordering. Then i used the `group` aesthetic to group them in the desired order on the x axis.

Here is my code:

```
df <- data.frame(Indep_var=c(90, 70, 30, 50),
                 Factor_1=c('Two', 'Two', 'One', 'One'),
                 Factor_2=c('Area_1', 'Area_2', 'Area_1', 'Area_2'),
                 SE=c(3, 4, 3.5, 5))

df2 <-  df %>% 
  # group by Factor_1
  group_by(Factor_1) %>% 
  # within each group, sort rows according to value of Indep_var
  arrange(Indep_var) %>% 
  # create new column with rank (or row number) within each group
  mutate(order_in_group=row_number()) %>% 
  # transform rank values into a factor
  mutate(order_in_group=as.factor(order_in_group)) %>%
  # remove grouping
  ungroup()

# in ggplot, group bars according to column `order_in_group` (I just added `group=order_in_group`)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=Factor_1, y=Indep_var, fill=Factor_2, group=order_in_group)) +
  geom_col(colour="black",width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Indep_var-SE, ymax=Indep_var+SE), width=0.2, position=position_dodge(0.5))
```

And here is my plot:

[image]